# Why We Use Non Modified Constructor in Enum in Java

Tags: java, constructor, enumeration

I have seen a java code where I see a non-modified constructor in an `enum`. Can anyone tell me why it is like that?

```
public enum myEnum{

  myEnum()
   {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you mean why there is no access modifier for the constructor, [that's because](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)

> In an `enum` declaration, **a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is `private`**.

and

> It is a compile-time error if a constructor declaration in an enum
>   declaration is `public` or `protected` (§6.6).

It's redundant to specify `private`, so some people don't.

Comment: I think your answer is correct; I was going on the direction of the constructor contents itself.